# Figuring out the CRC part of a packet

Tags: ida, encryption, crc, packet

Currently, I am trying to figure out the packet structure (for encryption) of an old MMO in order to create an emulator. Its official servers shut down 3 years ago and this version is over 11 years old.

After loading up the original server (it takes up ~3gb of RAM just to load and eats quite a lot of CPU, so that's why I want to emulate it) with IDA, I found that the polynomial is 0x8005 (32773) and that it was "Crc16". To further back that up, I found a series of bytes in memory when it's loaded:

```
00 00 [05 80] 0F 80 0A 00 1B 80 1E 00 14 00 11 80 33 80 36 00 3C 00 39 80 28 00
```

And, from IDA (pInitial is always 0 for some reason):

```
FnlApi::CCrc16::SetPolynomial(&this->__mCrc, 32773);
//////////////////////////////
v5 = FnlApi::CCrc16::CalcCrc(&this->__mCrc, pPack + 2, pLng - 2, 0);
//////////////////////////////
int result; // eax@1
const char *v5; // edx@1
__int16 v6; // bx@2
unsigned __int16 v7; // bx@2
bool v8; // zf@2

LOWORD(result) = pInitial;
v5 = pMsg;
do
{
    LOBYTE(v6) = 0;
    HIBYTE(v6) = result;
    v7 = this->__mTbl[(unsigned __int8)(*v5++ ^ BYTE1(result))] ^ v6;
    v8 = pLng-- == 1;
    result = v7;
}
while ( !v8 );
return result;
```

This is a packet from the server that isn't encrypted.

```
[1B 00] [00] [00 F2 2C 00 00 00] [31 32 37 2E 30 2E 30 2E 31 00 00 00 20 01 00 00 16 27]
```

As I understand, this is the packet "structure":

```
[Packet ID] [Key (00?)] [CRC, padding?] [Actual packet]
```

This is a packet from the server that is encrypted.

```
[2F 00] [74] [38 ED 2C 00 00 01] [93 85 AE 9A 9A 9A 9A 9A 9A 9A 9A 9A 9A 9A 9A 9A 9A 9A 9A F3 3C EF EF F9 AE 9A 9A 9A 9A 9A 9A 9A 9A 9A 9A 9A 9A 9A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00]
```

Decrypted, this is (I think):

```
[2F 00] [74] [38 ED 2C 00 00 01] [75 69 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 70 61 73 73 77 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC CC]
```

I think both of the packets's structure is:

```
[Packet ID] [Key] [CRC, padding?] [Actual packet]
```

Another packet that is encrypted with the same structure:

```
[18 00] [42] [56 D6 07 00 00 01] [2E 75 3D D2 75 03 CC 03 CD CC 03 8E 2D CC B1 6B 9F DB 6B D1 DB 6B 4F 4F D3 73 78 C6 AA 4B DF 63 1E 4A 18 C6 23 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00]
```

Decrypted:

```
[18 00] [42] [56 D6 07 00 00 01] [63 74 65 73 74 00 01 00 08 01 00 04 02 01 03 C7 0F AC C7 C4 AC C7 A3 A3 E7 5C 7F 05 CA 6D A0 77 46 64 F8 05 9E 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F]
```

I apologize for this being a mess, but I've been at it for days with no actual progress.

Edit:

My current class (with decryption working) is here: http://pastebin.com/7e05AJLa

Comment: AFAIR it does indeed look like a standard CRC16 but I find the 'decompilation' difficult to read/verify; at least with disassembly we know exactly what we have. Have you tried running a couple variants of CRC16 against existing packets, to see if the computed value matches? An alternative is ripping the disassembly of this small function - e.g. convert it to an .asm file or include it as inline assembly - in order to pit it directly against test implementations. If you post/link the disassembly I'll do it; I'm getting withdrawal symptoms from only doing C++/Delphi/C# for months..

Comment: @DarthGizka: Yes, I have. I've never gotten even a little bit close to the original packet. I've exported the file as an asm file in IDA and took the two CRC16 functions from it. http://www.mediafire.com/download/an38xbjh1k4hz99/crc16.asm

Comment: Thanks, I've downloaded it and will work on it tomorrow (almost midnight here). However, the .asm is missing the information from the call sites. I'm assuming that 0x8005 is passed to `SetPolynomial()`, as you said in your post. In the case of `CalcCrc()` it would be important to know the - probably constant - value of the last parameter, a.k.a. `uint16_t pInitial`. It's probably 0 or 0xFFFF, but gaming companies are known for strange humour like passing something like 123456789 (as seen in the Dragon Age savegame CRC). It would also be very helpful to have a file with a crapton of samples.

Comment: @DarthGizka: Thanks a lot! I would upload the entire disassembly plus the actual exe, but I'm not sure how copyright laws work when it comes to dead games. pInitial is 0 if I understand correctly. Perhaps this may help: http://www.mediafire.com/download/qer4ix72mmjkkma/fls.asm (oops, accidentally uploaded the full thing pre-edit) Also, I'll get back to you with those packets later.

Comment: Oops, I meant to say "entire disassembly plus the actual exe's". Anyways, I made a folder on MediaFire that contains packets logged with WPE Pro (actually lolsee or something). I exported it as a pac file and a txt file for your convenience. The two logs in the root (of the) folder contain 794 packets. The ones in the old folder contain 15 packets, as the name implies. URL: https://www.mediafire.com/folder/d21qwb1ppaw1a//TPacket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CRC is, as suspected, a fairly standard CRC16 with the polynomial 0x8005 (reflected: 0xA001). The only online calculators that I could find for this are:

- [BobTech's](http://www.bobtech.ro/tutoriale/porturi-si-interfete/51-crc-calculator) (clear the 'reverse data bytes' and 'reverse CRC' check boxes)
- [GHS Infotronic's](https://ghsi.de/CRC/index.php?Polynom=11000000000000101&Message=31+32+33+34+35+36+37+38+39) (the link has polynomial and message "123456789" already inserted)

The latter is particularly convenient for taking parts of the packet hex dumps, CRCing them, musing upon the results and then changing some bits before repeating the experiment...

Except for the polynomial - 0x8005 instead of 0x1021 - all the specifics are the same as for CRC-CCITT (XModem). If you plug in the 0x1021 poly then you can use a multitude of online checkers for verifying your own implementation, like [Lammert Bies's](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html), or indeed FoxPro's builtin CRC function (with 0x10000 as seed to force 0 as initial value, e.g. `sys(2007, "123456789", 0x10000)`).

Conversely, there are plenty of ready-made implementations where you only need to substitute 0x8005 for 0x1021. I've also found a [table-based implementation in C](https://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/proprietary_sub_1_ghz_simpliciti/f/156/t/31713) that already uses 0x8005.

The code in the disassembly is essentially the same as that in chapter 10 of the CRC bible, a.k.a. Ross Williams' [Painless Guide to CRC Error Detection Algorithms](http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt) ([HTML version here](http://www.repairfaq.org/filipg/LINK/F_crc_v3.html)):

```
r=0; 
while (len--) 
    r = (r<<8) ^ t[(r >> 8) ^ *p++];
```

This is readily apparent if you compare this to my transcription of the disassembly (which I did in C#, because I'm learning it ATM):

```
static ushort crc16 (byte[] pMsg, ushort pInitial = 0)
{
    uint eax = pInitial;

    for (int i = 0; i < pMsg.Length; ++i)  // EDX == pMsg + i
    {
        uint cl = ((eax >> 8) & 0xFF) ^ pMsg[i];
        uint bx = (eax & 0xFF) << 8;

        eax = bx ^ lookup[cl];
    }

    return (ushort)eax;
}
```

I've shown an intermediate rendition that still has the registers as value names, which makes it easily to correlate to the disassembly.

Sidenote: the disassembly shows IDA's age-old bug whereby it locally renames registers to the names of the parameters they hold on entry to the function.

E.g., for reading the disassembly of this particular function you need to substitute 'ecx' for 'this' mentally because otherwise it just doesn't make sense:

```
    ...
    xor this, this
    mov cl, ah
    xor cl, bl

    xor ebx, ebx
    mov bh, al
    and this, 0FFh
    movzx   this, cx
    xor bx, [esi+this*2]
    ...
```

It's simply ludicrous. I guess a certain someone needs to read up on the concept of live ranges, and why compilers bother to add live range data to the bits of debug info where IDA gets the name/register association from.

For completeness' sake here are the other parts of the CRC rig, for those who want to use C# for spelunking:

```
static ushort[] lookup;

static void initialise_lookup (ushort polynomial = 0x8005)
{
    for (uint edx = 0; edx <= 0xFF; ++edx)
    {
        uint ax = edx << 8;

        for (uint esi = 0; esi < 8; ++esi)
            if ((ax & 0x8000) != 0)
                ax = (ax << 1) ^ polynomial;
            else
                ax <<= 1;

        lookup[edx] = (ushort)ax;
    }
}

static ushort crc16 (string s, ushort initial = 0)
{
    return crc16(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s), initial);
}
```

That's it for the raw basis of the packet CRC. Now it's time to hammer out the specifics and to see if someone deviously passes something other than 0 for the initial value, or whether the resulting CRC is stomped on somehow before being inserted into the packet... Another thing to watch out for in the original EXE is that the CRC class might well get instantiated with different polynomials in different parts of the program.

Eyeballing the packets in `WPE_Plogtxt.txt` shows that only the third and fourths bytes (offsets 2 and 3) have enough entropy to be a CRC, and that the initial word is the length of the packet:

```
[u16 length] [u16 crc?] [5 headerish bytes] [payload]
```

Examples:

```
09 00 : 01 B9 : DF 07 00 00 01
09 00 : E2 CD : 75 00 00 00 01

0B 00 : 12 AD : 10 00 00 00 01 : 95 03 
0B 00 : 14 05 : 10 00 00 00 01 : A9 9A
0B 00 : 11 2B : 10 00 00 00 01 : BA CD
0B 00 : 77 D0 : 46 00 00 00 01 : 4D 2A

0C 00 : 2D B1 : 42 00 00 00 01 : B7 D1 90
0D 00 : 04 E6 : 6D 01 00 00 01 : F1 52 ED DF
0E 00 : 50 9D : 2C 00 00 00 01 : F7 E9 94 FC 3A
0F 00 : 4C 88 : 21 01 00 00 01 : 30 EB 62 D0 C4 D0
10 00 : 81 28 : 1B 00 00 00 01 : 64 CD E6 F0 24 CD F0
11 00 : C5 FB : 31 00 00 00 01 : 75 0F 13 10 DE 0F 11 2F 
12 00 : 9E F7 : 18 00 00 00 01 : 19 D8 F5 D8 F2 01 95 D8 D8
```

But sometimes the stuff doesn't fit at all:

```
13 00 : 00 00 : 03 00 00 00 00 : 00 00 0B E1 F5 05 00  00 00 00
```

In order to make quick headway it would be helpful to run analyses on large numbers of samples, i.e. directly on nice fat packet capture files. Where's this "PAC" format from?

Here are all samples of length 9 that I could find, to demonstrate why more analysis is necessary. Several of the samples differ only in the supposed CRC. This means that if these frames do contain CRCs then these must refer to some bigger frame of reference.

```
09 00 : C5 28 : 05 00 00 00 01
09 00 : CD 65 : 05 00 00 00 01
09 00 : EA A6 : 1E 00 00 00 00
09 00 : 58 29 : 2D 00 00 00 00
09 00 : CC 96 : 2D 00 00 00 00
09 00 : D0 B0 : 2D 00 00 00 00
09 00 : F8 8A : 2D 00 00 00 00
09 00 : 57 3C : 4F 00 00 00 01
09 00 : 41 47 : 5A 00 00 00 00
09 00 : 8E A2 : 5A 00 00 00 00
09 00 : DF B3 : 5A 00 00 00 00
09 00 : E2 CD : 75 00 00 00 01
09 00 : 01 B9 : DF 07 00 00 01
09 00 : 02 C9 : DF 07 00 00 01
09 00 : 0F 39 : DF 07 00 00 01
09 00 : 1A F2 : DF 07 00 00 01
09 00 : 36 7E : DF 07 00 00 01
09 00 : CD 65 : DF 07 00 00 01
09 00 : D0 55 : DF 07 00 00 01
09 00 : D2 D9 : DF 07 00 00 01
```

This complicates the picture and makes it more difficult to work out the specifics of the CRCs via packet analysis. It might be faster to attack the problem with IDA, by analysing references to the CRC function.

Comment: Thanks! Well, the PAC format is from WPE Pro, which is what I used to capture these packets. As for the "initial word" part, I checked again after adding another world to the world select page and it appears that you're right about it being the length of the packet. I've been at this for some weeks now with no progress at all, and it seems that I need to rewrite part of my code now that you said this... I've also checked the full .asm file and there was no other call to the SetPolynomial function. Do you have a suggestion on what packet capturing software I should use?

Comment: Didn't know the file format, that's all. And knowing the format is a precondition for having one's computer look at the file and confirm/disprove hypotheses regarding the packet structure. I'd attack the problem using IDA (and Cheat Engine, perhaps) to find the code that frames the packets - working backwards from the CRC calls or the network stack (winsock). It can be a lot of work, though. P.S.:

Comment: @Ray: you might want to look at game network libraries like [raknet](http://www.jenkinssoftware.com/features.html) to gain insights into problems and approaches specific to the network code of games. This should be helpful for understanding the whys and wherefores of the code you're analysing. Once you have acquired some reputation points here, you might want to set a [bounty](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help/bounty), to entice the gurus to take a look at your problem. Also, please read why [voting](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) anwsers is important

Comment: I see. Thank you so much! I'll keep at it then. I was wondering why there were so many packet "IDs" for server select. When you say "to entice the gurus", does that mean I should not flag this as answered?

Comment: You are right - the CRC has been identified and the question as stated has been answered. It's just that the underlying problem - which bytes to compute the CRC on and where exactly to insert it in the packets - has not yet been solved. I.e. to reverse-engineer the packet format. But that's more the job for a dedicated forum; Stack Exchange deals more with concrete, specific questions rather than open-ended research... I would have liked to chip in (like I did with the Dragon Age Inquisition savegame CRC) but over the coming months it's just not possible. :-/

Comment: Then I will continue experimenting by myself and ask for help on that one MMO "development" forum that has too much stuff on it. Thank you so much for all of this help!

Comment: I'm really, really sorry for poking this answered question with a really ugly stick, but I was wondering if you had any idea about a "correlation" between these: CRC of ED = 26E (server's EAX is 26E, byte 0), CRC of 2E = E4 (server's EAX is 6EE4, byte 0). I've been poking around for the last day or so with a debugger and the C# code you answered with and I'm really confused because the first byte fits but nothing after that.

Comment: @Raymonf: Stuff like that requires heavier communication than what the StackExchange Q&A format allows. If there is a spelunking forum for your game - e.g. similar to the [Dragon Age Inquisition modding forum](http://daitools.freeforums.org/) - then please post a link so that we can move the discussion there (and so that interested people can find it too). A forum is better than a chat because it allows asynchronous communication and does not require participants to be online with free time on their hands at the same time.